# Divs not showing on web page?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

On firebug(inspect element) they are shown as light grey compared to other elements. What is causing this I am running this website on wordrpress.

Comment: It means some library is missing and due to that these are not loading successfully (but printed as it is)

Comment: Most likely it simply means the topmost element in that structure is hidden (display:none)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click on the "outgrayed"

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-caroussel">
```

you will see in the right box that the style is set to `display: none;`